# Dual emission of constructor symbols

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor

Today, I discovered a rather interesting thing about either `g++` or `nm`...constructor definitions appear to have two entries in libraries.

I have a header `thing.hpp`:

```
class Thing
{
    Thing();

    Thing(int x);

    void foo();
};
```

And `thing.cpp`:

```
#include "thing.hpp"

Thing::Thing()
{ }

Thing::Thing(int x)
{ }

void Thing::foo()
{ }
```

I compile this with:

```
g++ thing.cpp -c -o libthing.a
```

Then, I run `nm` on it:

```
%> nm -gC libthing.a
0000000000000030 T Thing::foo()
0000000000000022 T Thing::Thing(int)
000000000000000a T Thing::Thing()
0000000000000014 T Thing::Thing(int)
0000000000000000 T Thing::Thing()
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

As you can see, both of the constructors for `Thing` are listed with two entries in the generated static library.  My `g++` is 4.4.3, but the same behavior happens in `clang`, so it isn't just a `gcc` issue.

This doesn't cause any apparent problems, but I was wondering:

- Why are defined constructors listed twice?
- Why doesn't this cause "multiple definition of symbol __" problems?

---

**EDIT**: For Carl, the output without the `C` argument:

```
%> nm -g libthing.a
0000000000000030 T _ZN5Thing3fooEv
0000000000000022 T _ZN5ThingC1Ei
000000000000000a T _ZN5ThingC1Ev
0000000000000014 T _ZN5ThingC2Ei
0000000000000000 T _ZN5ThingC2Ev
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

As you can see...the same function is generating multiple symbols, which is still quite curious.

And while we're at it, here is a section of generated assembly:

```
.globl _ZN5ThingC2Ev
        .type   _ZN5ThingC2Ev, @function
_ZN5ThingC2Ev:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   _ZN5ThingC2Ev, .-_ZN5ThingC2Ev
        .align 2
.globl _ZN5ThingC1Ev
        .type   _ZN5ThingC1Ev, @function
_ZN5ThingC1Ev:
.LFB2:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

So the generated code is...well...the same.

---

**EDIT**: To see what constructor actually gets called, I changed `Thing::foo()` to this:

```
void Thing::foo()
{
    Thing t;
}
```

The generated assembly is:

```
.globl _ZN5Thing3fooEv
        .type   _ZN5Thing3fooEv, @function
_ZN5Thing3fooEv:
.LFB550:
        .cfi_startproc
        .cfi_personality 0x3,__gxx_personality_v0
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $48, %rsp
        movq    %rdi, -40(%rbp)
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _ZN5ThingC1Ev
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    _ZN5ThingD1Ev
        leave
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

So it is invoking the complete object constructor.

Comment: You're obfuscating your problem with the `-C` flag to `nm`.  If you leave it off, you'll see that the constructors that are emitted in fact have different symbols (which is the answer to your second question).  I have no idea why two identical constructors are emitted with different symbol names, but I'm trying to read up on that now... more if I figure it out.

Comment: Your output looks roughly the same as what I get here - so the question, really, is "what's the difference between the mangled name with a `C1` in it versus that with a `C2` in it?", and I have no answer to that question.  I'm surprised the documentation doesn't have more about it.... hrm.

Comment: Its interesting that the exact same behavior happens in two different compilers.

Comment: I'd be interested to see which one a subclass calls and which one `new` calls...

Comment: @Ben - the OP says clang does it too.  That's not really that surprising though; clang's behaviour often mimics gcc's.

Comment: @Carl: Ah yes, I skimmed over that sentence.  oops.

Comment: OK - so I looked in http://cocotron-tools-gpl3.googlecode.com/svn-history/r60/trunk/binutils/libiberty/cp-demangle.c (implementation of `d_ctor_dtor_name`), and found that the `C1` means it's a `gnu_v3_complete_object_ctor`, and a `C2` means that it's a `gnu_v3_base_object_ctor`.  Does that mean anything to the C++ experts?  I'm guessing it's like @jswolf19 says, they're for subclasses vs new object creation.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613870/gnu-gcc-g-why-does-it-generate-multiple-dtors

Answer (score 165, accepted):

We'll start by declaring that [GCC follows](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compatibility.html) [the Itanium C++ ABI](http://web.archive.org/web/20100315072857/http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html).

---

According to the ABI, the mangled name for your `Thing::foo()` is easily parsed:

```
_Z     | N      | 5Thing  | 3foo | E          | v
prefix | nested | `Thing` | `foo`| end nested | parameters: `void`
```

You can read the constructor names similarly, as below. Notice how the constructor "name" isn't given, but instead a `C` clause:

```
_Z     | N      | 5Thing  | C1          | E          | i
prefix | nested | `Thing` | Constructor | end nested | parameters: `int`
```

---

But what's this `C1`? Your duplicate has `C2`. What does this *mean*?

Well, [this is quite simple too](http://web.archive.org/web/20100315072857/http://www.codesourcery.com/public/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling):

```
  <ctor-dtor-name> ::= C1   # complete object constructor
                   ::= C2   # base object constructor
                   ::= C3   # complete object allocating constructor
                   ::= D0   # deleting destructor
                   ::= D1   # complete object destructor
                   ::= D2   # base object destructor
```

---

Wait, why is this *simple*? This class has no base. Why does it have a "complete object constructor" **and** a "base object constructor" for each?

- [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355438/overloading-operator-delete-in-a-base-class) implies to me that this is simply a by-product of polymorphism support, even though it's not actually required in this case.
- Note that `c++filt` used to include this information in its demangled output, [but doesn't any more](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=35201).
- [This forum post](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=2930) asks the same question, and the only response doesn't do any better at answering it, except for the implication that GCC **could** avoid emitting two constructors when polymorphism is not involved, and that this behaviour ought to be improved in the future.
- [This newsgroup posting](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/gdb/2004-07/msg00163.html) describes a problem with setting breakpoints in constructors due to this dual-emission. It's stated again that the root of the issue is support for polymorphism.

In fact, [this is listed as a GCC "known issue"](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#known,):

> #### G++ emits two copies of constructors and destructors.
>
> In general there are three types of constructors (and
> destructors).
>
> - The complete object constructor/destructor.
> - The base object constructor/destructor.
> - The allocating constructor/deallocating destructor.
>
> The first two are different, when virtual base classes are
> involved.

---

The meaning of these different constructors [seems to be as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613870/gnu-gcc-g-why-does-it-generate-multiple-dtors/6614369#6614369):

- The "complete object constructor". It additionally constructs virtual base classes.
- The "base object constructor". It creates the object itself, as well as data members and non-virtual base classes.
- The "allocating object constructor". It does everything the complete object constructor does, plus it calls operator new to actually allocate the memory... *but apparently this is not usually seen.*

> If you have no virtual base classes, [the first two] are are
> identical; GCC will, on sufficient optimization levels, actually alias
> the symbols to the same code for both.

Comment: Hooray for an answer - I think I was closing in on this, but it's good to see the right information.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: +1, for a very detailed research for answering the Q.

Comment: This is an awesome answer, but is there documentation for that the difference between these constructor types?  Mostly: What is an "allocating constructor" and a "deleting destructor"?  Are they for overloading `operator new` and `operator delete`?

Comment: @Travis: I'm not entirely sure yet. bdonlan [argh, SO, quit limiting my notifications in comments FFS] pointed out [this highly-related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613870/gnu-gcc-g-why-does-it-generate-multiple-dtors), and there appears to be lots of pertinent information there.

Comment: @Travis: Yes, I think that they are. I don't want this answer to turn into general documentation for the entire construction/destruction process, but I briefly cover that in my latest edit.

Comment: On the *apparently not usually seen* comment, the Itanium ABI does not require generation or use of *allocating object constructor* for classes without a virtual destructor. Furthermore, gcc implementation *never* generates or uses it. [It does generate and use the deallocating constructor, but not the allocating constructor, and I don't quite understand where that constructor would be useful at all...]