# ARM C++ ABI: Constructor/destructor return values

Tags: c++, arm, abi

I've been reading through Clang source code and discovered something interesting about the ARM C++ ABI that I can't seem to understand the justification for. From the an online version of the [ARM ABI documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0041d/index.html):

> This ABI requires C1 and C2 constructors to return *this* (instead of being void functions) so that a C3 constructor
>   can tail call the C1 constructor and the C1 constructor can tail call C2.

(and similarly for non-virtual destructors)

I'm not sure what `C1`, `C2`, and `C3` reference here...this section is meant to be a modification of §3.1.5 from the generic (i.e. Itanium) ABI, but that section (at least in [this online verison](http://mentorembedded.github.com/cxx-abi/abi.html)) simply states:

> Constructors return **void** results.

Anyway, I really can't figure out what the purpose of this is: how does making a constructor return *this* allow tail call optimization, and in what circumstances?

As far I can tell, the only time a constructor could tail call another with the same `this` return value would be the case of a derived class with a single base class, a trivial constructor body, no members with non-trivial constructors, and no virtual table pointer. In fact, it seems like it would actually be easier, not harder, to optimize with a tail call with a `void` return, because then the restriction of a single base class could be eliminated (in the multiple base class case, the `this` pointer returned from the last called constructor will not be the `this` pointer of the derived object).

What am I missing here? Is there something about the ARM calling convention that makes the `this` return necessary?

Comment: I suspect that C1, C2 and C3 refer to "complete object constructor", "base object constructor" and "complete object allocating constructor", about which you can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols)

Comment: @Michael ahh, THAT makes sense (knew those existed, but didn't know the mangled name convention...I assumed `C1`,`C2`, and `C3` referred to constructors in some hierarchy in some diagram that was missing). I still don't understand the destructor case though.

Comment: @Michael ok, thanks for the link, understand the destructor case too now, I think...if no one answers this authoritatively I'll answer it myself at some point

Comment: From an efficiency point of view, this makes a lot of sense. Constructors presumably use the same conventions as other functions: `this` is passed in `r1`, but not required to be preserved by the callee.   Ensuring it's passed out in `r0` ensures that the callee doesn't need to stash a copy.

Comment: @Marko yeah, that's the explicit reason given in the ABI for the `D1` and `D2` destructors (see [Michael's linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols) for definitions) to return `this` actually...constructors can benefit similarly although the main reason is to allow tail calls from `C3` constructors. anyway, it's pretty clear now given those definitions, I'll self-answer if no one else decides to.

Comment: @Marko you mean the "caller" doesn't have to stash a copy, right?

Comment: @StephenLin I did indeed.

Comment: @Marko `this` should be passed in `r0` .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, helpful link from @Michael made this all clear...`C1`, `C2`, and `C3` refer to the name-mangling of the "complete object constructor", "base object constructor", and "complete object allocating constructor", respectively, from the Itanium ABI:

```
  <ctor-dtor-name> ::= C1   # complete object constructor
                   ::= C2   # base object constructor
                   ::= C3   # complete object allocating constructor
                   ::= D0   # deleting destructor
                   ::= D1   # complete object destructor
                   ::= D2   # base object destructor
```

The `C3`/"complete object allocating constructor" is a version of the constructor that, rather than operating on already allocated storage passed to it via the `this` parameter, allocates memory internally (via `operator new`) and then calls the `C1`/"complete object constructor", which is the normal constructor used for the complete object case. Since the `C3` constructor must return the `this` pointer to the newly allocated and constructed object, the `C1` constructor must also return the `this` pointer in order for a tail call to be used.

The `C2`/"base object constructor" is the constructor called by derived classes when constructing a base class subobject; the semantics of `C1` and `C2` constructors differ in case of `virtual` inheritance and could be implemented differently for optimization purposes as well. In the case of `virtual` inheritance, a `C1` constructor could be implemented with calls to `virtual` base class constructors followed by a tail call to a `C2` constructor, so the latter should also return `this` if the former does.

The destructor case is slightly different but related. As per the ARM ABI:

> Similarly, we require D2 and D1 to return this so that D0 need not save and restore *this* and D1 can tail call D2 (if there are no virtual bases). D0 is still a void function.

The `D0`/"deleting destructor" is used when deleting an object, it calls the `D1`/"complete object destructor" and calls `operator delete` with the `this` pointer afterwards to free the memory. Having the `D1` destructor return `this` allows the `D0` destructor to use its return value to call `operator delete`, rather than having to save it to another register or spill it to memory; similarly, the `D2`/"base object destructor" should return `this` as well.

The ARM ABI also adds:

> We do not require thunks to virtual destructors to return *this*. Such a thunk would have to adjust the destructor’s
>   result, preventing it from tail calling the destructor, and nullifying any possible saving.
>
> Consequently, only non-virtual calls of D1 and D2 destructors can be relied on to return *this*.

If I understand this correctly, it means that this save-restore-elision optimization can only be used when `D0` calls `D1` statically (i.e. in the case of a non-`virtual` destructor).