# Linker. How could symbol be defined and undefined simultaneously?

Tags: c++, linker

```
$ nm --demangle /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/libsupc++.a  | grep "__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info"
```

gives following output:

```
0000000000000000 T __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info()
0000000000000000 T __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info()
0000000000000000 T __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info()
                 U __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info()
                 U __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::~__class_type_info()
```

So, how to interpret this output?

1. Here is multiple definitions of the symbol (three `T`'s) - how it could be? Why linker produced such library with violated `ODR`? What is the purpose? And why all of them have the same (and strange) address  (`0000000000000000`)?
2. How the same symbol could be both defined (`T`) and undefined (`U`) simultaneously?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6613870/1147772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static library (archive file, `.a`) is essentially a collection of individual `.o` files (plus some indexing information so the linker can find the `.o` files it needs). Some of those undefined symbols are in a different object than the one that defines them. If you look at the full output of `nm` this becomes clear. (Or use the `-o` flag to `nm`.)

The reason you have multiple defined symbols is that `demangle` isn't a 1-to-1 operation. In my copy of `libsupc++`, those three definitions are:

```
0000000000000000 T _ZN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoD0Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoD1Ev
0000000000000000 T _ZN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoD2Ev
```

Why are there several symbols which all demangle to the destructor? They're [destructors for different situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453880/1750757). gcc uses the Itanium ABI for C++, whose [name mangling rules are described here.](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15453880/1750757) is better than your [destructors for different situations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6614369/821637).

Comment: Thanks, @VictorPolevoy! I've changed the link to that one.