# Why are C3 allocating constructors never used?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor

Some of us know that there are [several constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols) possible for C++ object, C1 and C2. But GCC sources says that there is can be third variant of constructor, the C3 "complete object allocating constructor" (check `gcc-4.8/gcc/cp/mangle.c` file just before `write_special_name_constructor` function):

http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/cp/mangle.c;h=10c2e2beb0c422e4f56e17e7659fbeb4ab3ee31b;hb=refs/tags/gcc-4_8_1-release#l1644

```
1645 /* Handle constructor productions of non-terminal <special-name>.
1646    CTOR is a constructor FUNCTION_DECL.
1647 
1648      <special-name> ::= C1   # complete object constructor
1649                     ::= C2   # base object constructor
1650                     ::= C3   # complete object allocating constructor
1651 
1652    Currently, allocating constructors are never used.    <<<<<
1653 
1654    We also need to provide mangled names for the maybe-in-charge
1655    constructor, so we treat it here too.  mangle_decl_string will
1656    append *INTERNAL* to that, to make sure we never emit it.  */
```

Why the C3 may be needed, but not used by GCC? 
Is there any popular C++ compiler, which generates C3 constructors?

Is the C3 documented in any ABI pdf?

Comment: It's mentioned in the Itanium C++ ABI: http://www.swag.uwaterloo.ca/acd/docs/ItaniumC++ABI.htm When and why (or why not) it's used -- no idea :-/

Comment: N.B. the official Itanium ABI URL is http://www.codesourcery.com/cxx-abi/

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that `C3` is an optimized version of `::operator new(sizeof(class))` followed by `C1`, i.e. a pre-inlined version. GCC has to create it in case another compiler uses it. That may obviously depend on inlining decisions, which are generally non-trivial.

Comment: Actually, last time I looked gcc *doesn't* create a C3 symbol.

Comment: Hmm, that would be unfunny when linking against an object file which does expect it. The idea of an ABI is that you can link binaries.

Comment: Is there a way to generate also C3 ?

Comment: What is "pre-inlining"?