# g++ generating the "complete object allocating constructor"

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, abi, compiler-specific

Is there a way(an argument) to make the g++ compiler to generate the "complete object allocating constructor"(C3) and the "deleting destructor"(D0)?

I loooked into this [Why are C3 allocating constructors never used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728634/why-are-c3-allocating-constructors-never-used) , does not answer my question.