# Why constructor/destructor are defined like this in g++ produced assembly code?

Tags: c++, assembly, elf

I wrote a simple C++ program with which defined a class like below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Computer
{
public:
  Computer();
  ~Computer();
};

Computer::Computer()
{
}

Computer::~Computer()
{
}

int main()
{
  Computer compute;  
    return 0;
}
```

When I use `g++`(Test is on x86 32bit Linux with g++ 4.6.3.) to produce the `ctors` and `dtors`, I get these definitions at the end of section `.ctors`.

```
    .globl  _ZN8ComputerC1Ev
    .set    _ZN8ComputerC1Ev,_ZN8ComputerC2Ev
    .globl  _ZN8ComputerD1Ev
    .set    _ZN8ComputerD1Ev,_ZN8ComputerD2Ev
```

After digging into the assembly code produced, I figured out that `_ZN8ComputerC1Ev` should be the function name which is used when class `Computer` is constructed, while `_ZN8ComputerC2Ev` is the name of class `Computer`'s constructor. The same thing happens in `Computer`'s destructor declaring and invoking.

It seems that a **table** is built, linking the constructor and its implementation.

So my questions are:

1. What actually is this  constructor/destructor information for?
2. Where can I find them in `ELF` format?

I dumped related `.ctors` and `.init_array` section, but I just can not find the meta data that defined the relation between `_ZN8ComputerC1Ev` and `_ZN8ComputerC2Ev`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no table here. `.globl` and `.set` are so-called *assembler directives* or *pseudo ops*. They signal something to the assembler, but do not necessarily result in production of actual code or data. From [the docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html):

> `.global` *symbol*, `.globl` *symbol*
>
> `.global` makes the *symbol* visible to `ld`. If you define *symbol* in your
>   partial program, its value is made available to other partial programs
>   that are linked with it. Otherwise, *symbol* takes its attributes from a
>   symbol of the same name from another file linked into the same
>   program.
>
> `.set` *symbol, expression*
>
> Set the value of *symbol* to *expression*. This changes *symbol*'s value and
>   type to conform to *expression*.

So the fragment you quote just ensures that the constructor is available for linking in case it's referenced by other compile units. The only effect of it you normally see in the final ELF is the presence of those symbols in the symbol table (if it has not been stripped).

Now, you may be curious about why you have two different names for the constructor (e.g. `_ZN8ComputerC1Ev` and `_ZN8ComputerC2Ev`). The answer is somewhat complicated so I will refer you to another SO question which addresses it in some detail:

[Dual emission of constructor symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols)