# Too many constructor symbols

Tags: c++

When compiled, this:

```
template <typename T>
struct ConstArray {
///MEMBERS
    T* data_;
    T* end_;

///Constructors
    ConstArray(T* data, T* end) : data_(data), end_(end) {}
};

template struct ConstArray<const char>;
```

gives me (`nm -C *.o`):

```
0000000000000000 W ConstArray<char const>::ConstArray(char const*, char const*)
0000000000000000 W ConstArray<char const>::ConstArray(char const*, char const*)
0000000000000000 n ConstArray<char const>::ConstArray(char const*, char const*)
```

I seem to get three symbols (2 W + 1 n (don't know what that is)) for each constructor I define. Functions seem to give me just one as expected. 
Could somebody please explain why this is or point me to an explanation?

Comment: Seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols

Comment: yepp, just found it https://www.google.com/search?q=multiple+constructors+generated and there was another great answer somewhere, I just don't know what search words to use.

Comment: @Michael Thanks a lot. This question is a duplicate up to the unexplained n symbol.

Comment: `end_(end_)` should be `end_(end)`. Using same name instead of underscory-warts avoids this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I can see why this symbols appears in `nm` output, but I can't tell if it should/shouldn't be there and what exactly `n` means. Maybe if someone is familiar with this, he can post full answer.

If you make `objdump -t ./obj.o` you can see a symbol table. Except 2 constructors and many other symbols I see

```
00000000 l       .group 00000000 _ZN10ConstArrayIKcEC5EPS0_S2_
```

there. The flag is only `l` which means it is local and not debug, so I see it in `nm` output as third symbol.

If I do `nm -g ./obj.o` to see only extern symbols, I see only 2 `W` constructors and when I do `nm -a ./obj.o` I see all the symbols and also marked in `objdump -x` as `debug`. And I also see there some debug symbols that are`n`-flagged in `nm -a` output.

So I don't know what `n` means, but the third symbol is somehow related to `.group` section of `elf` file. Which is responsible for grouping symbols together.