# Why would a compiler generate duplicate symbols in the same object?

Tags: c++, g++, symbols, clang++, nm

Take the following source code:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(){}
};

Foo f;
```

When compiled with `clang++`, it creates a single symbol for the constructor:

```
clang++ -c foo.cpp
nm -C foo.o | grep Foo
0000000000000000 W Foo::Foo()
```

---

However, when compiled with `g++`, it creates multiple symbols for the constructor:

```
g++ -c foo.cpp;
nm -C foo.o | grep Foo
0000000000000000 W Foo::Foo()
0000000000000000 W Foo::Foo()
0000000000000000 n Foo::Foo()
```

**Why would `g++` create duplicate weak symbols in the same object file?**
My only theory, is that it has to do with inlining, but that's just a guess.

---

I should note, the mangled names appear as so:

```
g++ -c foo.cpp; nm foo.o | grep Foo 
0000000000000000 W _ZN3FooC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN3FooC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN3FooC5Ev
```

So although the unmangled names are the same, `ZN3FooC1Ev` and `ZN3FooC2Ev` are different.

Comment: If you ask `g++` to optimize with `g++ -O -c` it is emitting only one symbol.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Oh.  If I optimize on either `clang++` or `g++`, it creates no constructor symbols at all.  just a symbol for `f` (uninitialized data section)

Comment: Also, when you look at the assembly code (`g++ -fverbose-asm -S`), you get two different weak symbols `_ZN3FooC1Ev` and `_ZN3FooC2Ev` which gets demangled the same way to `Foo::Foo()`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Right!  But they can't be different constructors can they?  I've applied `=deleted` to all the implicits, so its clearly nothing like a move constructor or anything.

Comment: Try also `g++ -fdump-tree-all` and look inside the various dump files.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This is a portal to a whole new rabbit hole.

Comment: Sorry, why rabbit and what is (figuratively) a rabbit hole? I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's an idiom for "exploring the unknown".  `-fdump-tree-all` is very helpful.

Comment: You should edit your question and also ask the difference between `_ZN3FooC1Ev` and `_ZN3FooC2Ev`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dual emission of constructor symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921295/dual-emission-of-constructor-symbols)